# Can I use linq to join two result sets on an ordinal/ index #?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use linq to objects with html agility pack to join two result sets on their relative ordinal position. One set is a list of headers, the other is a set of tables, with each table corresponding to one of the header values. Each set has a count of five. I've read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703091/using-linq-to-xml-how-can-i-join-two-sets-of-data-based-on-ordinal-position) which looks very similar, but can't get it to translate to my purposes. 
Here is what I'm using to get the two html node collections:

```
HtmlNodeCollection ratingsChgsHdrs = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='calendar-header']");
HtmlNodeCollection ratingsChgsTbls = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='calendar-table']");
```

The collection `ratingsChgsHdrs` contains the headers for each of the tables in `ratingsChgsTbls`, within the InnerText property. The end result I'm looking for is one result set consisting of all of the rows from all five tables, with the header value added as a property to each row. I hope that is clear.. any help would be great.

Comment: The post you linked to contains the solution. Zip both sequences together.

Comment: So what's the problem? What's wrong with the solution in that other question? How is that not answering your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
ratingsChgsHdrs.Select((x, i) => new { x, ratingsChgsTbls.ElementAt(i) });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as well as patience.. I'm reading up on linq/ enumerable methods that aren't familiar to me. 'Answered' for taking the time to offer a suggestion.